# Can you use PHP inside a .js file that you're minifying with the minify library?

Tags: javascript, php, minify

I am using some PHP inside a javascript file. I am also using the minify library (https://code.google.com/p/minify/) to minify stylesheets and javascript.
I rewrite the request for script.js to script.php and in script.php i do this (code is abstracted, so doesn't make any sense):

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/x-javascript");
$var = 'hi'; ?>
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert('<?php echo $var ?>');
});
```

When I request script.js directly it works. When I include it in the string to be minified like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="min/b=javascript&amp;f=script.js"></script>
```

It gives me a 400 bad request. I've set the debugging variable true inside the minify config. With no result. Is this just not possible? Or am I doing something wrong? I can't find any other questions on this topic.

Comment: What is the name of the php file?  It looks like your src is an improper URL.  At the very least you need a ? to start the query string, but is it min.php or min/index.php or something else?

Comment: This is a command line tool? If so, you should be able to use a bit of bash to make it work. Something like `php source.php | minify > source.min.js`

Comment: I have used the minify library in almost every project. I know exactly how it works and the problem is not a misspelled src. Note that disabling the rewrite from js to php results in the file being minified correctly if it exists. The ? is not needed in the src since the .htaccess in the /min folder rewrites the url properly. I'm guessing the problem should lie somewhere in the request headers or additional .htaccess rules to serve te file correctly.

Comment: Nope Scott, it's a PHP library.

Comment: I think the issue is that the minify library reads the source files to be minified - but instead it needs to process the output of the php.

Comment: So I would have to edit the way the library works?

Answer (score 1):

You should send that variable separately from your js code, for example in a config json file or in a script tag in your html, etc...
After that your scripts won't be depend on the php variable so they will be static and minifiable.

Some explanation:

Okay first of all. Php runs on the server machine and javascript runs on the client's browser. These are completely different machines, and different platforms. I hope you understand that.
In order to maintain (develop, debug, etc...) code, we have to organize it. Mixin php and javascript code make thing very unorganized. If you want to debug a php feature you want to read php code, not js code and vica-versa. It is called noisy code, there is php noise in your js code or there is js noise in your php code. To avoid these problems by the simple languages like html, we use templates, by the complex languages like javascript, we should create an application interface, and through that interface should the client side js and the server side php application communicate, send data, etc... It is good, because it is controlled, organized, etc..., we always know where the data comes from, and that's very important if you want to find the source of a bug or understand how the current code works. By this size of code it is irrelevant, but over hundred lines you will feel the difference...

You can find several questions about this, I think you should read this one:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript

Comment: It's a solution for passing PHP variables to scripts yeah, but some inline scripts get more complicated very easily. I'm just curious as to whether this is possible. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Theoretically possible, in practice not, the uglifier should know both of the languages... It is not a good practice to mix languages that way... Btw you should use json_encode whenever you send a variable from php to js, unless you want to be XSS attacked.

Comment: I'll append my answer why you should not do this.

Comment: Thing is I am dealing with a website I need to optimize. Lot of inline scripts with PHP in them. Ugly source code. I would like for an easy way to minify them together with the regular scripts served via src. Maybe you can eloborate on the topic as to why it is always bad practice to mix PHP with javascript? Because I think there are certainly some cases where it can be very benefinicial.

Comment: Ah... I'll await your response.

Comment: Ye fixing legacy systems with spaghetti code is a hard work, it is easier to write them again from zero if you want to add serious modifications.

Comment: I don't think this can be done automatically without a lot of effort from you. As far as I know there is no js minifier which recognizes php code, so you have to teach your current minifier to do that...

Comment: Btw if you want to optimize your code, the first step to separate js and php codes. After that php will be a lot faster because the js code will be served as static files and php will never allocate the server memory to store js code as a string... After that your js code will be cacheable by the browser, so it won't download it by every page load. I think that would make things a lot faster...

Comment: Probably better off to leave it as it is then. The invested time would not weigh up to the benefits. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes, I think so. If it is a big site, refactoring can take months... Rewriting the whole site with a good framework would take a fragment of that time...

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's possible if you use a `Minify_Source` object instead of a static file path. E.g. You can use the output of a PHP script as the input source to minify.

The docs [has a section on this](https://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/CustomSource#Non-File_Sources) and mentions its limitations.

If your script's output changes per user or frequently, you probably don't want to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the doc reference. You're probably right, because the person whom created the PHP inside the javascript in the first place, probably wanted to make it dynamic. If you were to minify that output you could only present the result to the client that uses the exact same variables that were used to minify the script.